# Best language for live data gui

Tags: user-interface, search, analysis

I am trying to create a GUI/ application which can take live data from OSI PI and visualize it in real time on a graph. Which coding language would be the best for that?

Comment: choose the language you use the most, then search on google "graph library for MY_LANGUAGE"... for me the simplest way to create GUI is by "web development" since there are a lot of open source libraries that you can use. that take as parameter some JSON files or some array and make them as a chart. **here an example** https://www.chartjs.org/ or for more complex things **D3.js** https://d3js.org/